# How to check if the given string is a valid 'PropertyName' and 'PropertyValue' for the style attribute of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to dynamically add/edit a property of the style attribute based on the user input. The user can give the **Property Name** and **Property Value** as a string. I would need to validate, if the given string is a valid **property name/property value** for the **style** attribute of an HTML element before applying.

Is there any way to achieve the above validation?

Is there any javascript function that can validate the given string for valid **property name/property value** or function that returns all valid properties/values for a particular property of the style attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is applying the style and checking for its existence. This function can use some improvements but it works or at least demonstrates the concept.

```js
function is_valid_css_prop(prop, value) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(div)
  div.style[prop] = value;
  var obj = getComputedStyle(div);

  var found = false;
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (key == prop && value == obj[key]) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  document.body.removeChild(div)
  return found;
}


console.log(is_valid_css_prop("position", "above"));
console.log(is_valid_css_prop("position", "absolute"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This function meets our requirement. We will try this approach.